# vectorization of loop in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I've been trying to vectorize the following with no such luck:

Consider two data frames.  One is a list of dates:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']

index = pd.date_range('1/1/15','8/31/18')

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols )
```

What i'm doing currently is looping thru `df` and getting the counts of all rows that are less than or equal to the date in question with my main (large) dataframe `df_main`

```
for x in range(len(index)):
    temp_arr = []

    active = len(df_main[(df_main.n_date <= index[x])]

    temp_arr = [index[x],active]

    df= df.append(pd.Series(temp_arr,index=cols) ,ignore_index=True)
```

Is there a way to vectorize the above?

Comment: You don't want to append to a df within a loop, since append copies every time. You should append data frames to a list, and then concatenate once at the end. This could speed things up significantly if your df is large and the append is only a small subset every time.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like the following

```
#initializing
mycols = ['col1', 'col2']
myindex = pd.date_range('1/1/15','8/31/18')
mydf = pd.DataFrame(columns = mycols )

#create df_main (that has each of myindex's dates minus 10 days)
df_main = pd.DataFrame(data=myindex-pd.Timedelta(days=10), columns=['n_date'])

#wrap a dataframe around a list comprehension
mydf = pd.DataFrame([[x, len(df_main[df_main['n_date'] <= x])] for x in myindex])
```